# В чем разница b = reader.read() и reader.ready()

Tags: java, inputstream

решая задачки на Степике столкнулся с тем что валидатор принял ответ

```
public static String readAsStringNew(InputStream inputStream, Charset charset) throws IOException {

        StringWriter string = new StringWriter();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset);
        int b;
        while ((b = reader.read()) != -1) {
            string.write(b);
        }

        return string.toString();
    }
```

но не принимает

```
public static String readAsString(InputStream inputStream, Charset charset) throws IOException {

        StringWriter r = new StringWriter();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset);
        while (reader.ready()){
            r.write(reader.read());
        }
        return r.toString();
    }
```

Ключевое отличие как я понимаю `(b = reader.read()) != -1)` и  `reader.ready()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[InputStreamReader.ready](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#ready--):

> **Returns:**
>
> True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input, false otherwise. Note that returning false does not guarantee that the
> next read will block.

Метод `ready` может вернуть `false`, а последующий `read` может прочитать ещё данные из потока. Потому что `ready` - средство для организации неблокирующего чтения, а не проверка того что данные закончились вообще.

То, что данные закончились вообще можно узнать только по неуспеху `read`.

Валидатор прав. Вариант с `ready` может совсем ничего не прочитать, или прочитать только те данные, которые были помещены в буфер при открытии ридера. Тестировать на данных, которые заведомо больше буфера. Иначе ошибка может быть не заметна.

Comment: Не совсем понятно: кто такой Валидатор?

Comment: @RomanC, см. первую строку вопроса. Валидатор - верховное божество Степика. Все ему поклоняются.